# Why response take long time in ajax but php code executed quickly?

Tags: php, ajax, api

I made a PHP application and it requires API Response from a server and it checks with mysql database.

Every time it takes long time to execute, minimum time to get response is 3 seconds and goes 90 seconds and so on.

I have attached the screenshot of two files for one is continuous request delayed response and another is waiting time.

I want to know the reason for the waiting time and blocked time in response. But when I check the php code execution it done in less than one seconds.

Whether I want to improve php code or that API server?

[image: Screen1 - All request]

[image: Screen2 - Waiting Time]

Comment: Please add your code to the question (as text and not images) - at the moment it's only guesswork as to your problem.

Comment: I'm asking how to reduce the waiting time in ajax call..but php executed in few microseconds but the response is not in few microseconds.....how to improve that.?